# ExoPlayer.EventListener doesn't work

Tags: android, exoplayer

I have implemented `ExoPlayer.EventListener` interface in order to override method `public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error)` so I can intercept exception and restart the player if specific exception has been thrown. The problem is that this method has never been called even though the error `BehindLiveWindowException` had occurred.

Does anybody know why this method has not executed?

[My code sample](http://pastebin.com/xzRt7LpX)